# AspNet Core3 Identity configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to follow a little bit out of date tutorial project for AspNet Core 1.1
(while I'm using Visual Studio 2019 preview 2.0,
 and .net core v3.0.0-preview9 installed)

I already have a database with a couple of tables created by EntityFrameworkCore3.00-preview,
it works fine.

Now I'm trying to add autorization into project
So I derive my database context class from IdentityDbContext,

`public class MyDbContext : IdentityDbContext`

instead of

`public class WorldContext : DbContext`

make add-migration and update-database and in database I see many new tables

At this point my application could start, but at the very moment as I added a line

`services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>();`

to ConfigurationServices in Startup.cs

application crashes with message:

> System.AggregateException
>     HResult=0x80131500
>     Message=Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.ISecurityStampValidator Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SecurityStampValidator`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.ITwoFactorSecurityStampValidator Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.TwoFactorSecurityStampValidator`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserClaimsPrincipalFactory`2[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IRoleStore`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]'.)
>     Source=Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
>     StackTrace:
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(IEnumerable`1 serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionContainerBuilderExtensions.BuildServiceProvider(IServiceCollection services, ServiceProviderOptions options)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.DefaultServiceProviderFactory.CreateServiceProvider(IServiceCollection containerBuilder)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.ServiceFactoryAdapter`1.CreateServiceProvider(Object containerBuilder)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.CreateServiceProvider()
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
>      at TheWorld.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\mli2805\source\repos\TheWorld\TheWorld\Program.cs:line 10
>
> Inner Exception 1:
>   InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.ISecurityStampValidator Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SecurityStampValidator`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]'.
>
> Inner Exception 2:
>   InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]'.

If I implement
 `public class MyUserStore : IUserStore<IdentityUser>`

and add a line 
 `services.AddScoped<IUserStore<IdentityUser>, MyUserStore>();`

to ConfigurationServices, I receive next error about

> Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IRoleStore

and so on, though in tutorial there is nothing about implementation all those interfaces.
It's seems to me that I do something wrong in configuration services?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to add `AddEntityFrameworkStores<TContext>()`:

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<WorldContext>();
```

FWIW, ASP.NET Core 1.1 is not "a little outdated". Documentation referencing that version is so outdated as to be virtually useless. So much changed in 2.X, and even more in 3.X. You should find a different article/tutorial.

Comment: Yes! I just found out that I missed this line. Thanks anyway!

Comment: What about if we don't want to use EF?

Comment: Then you have to either create custom store classes or find a library that provides these already for your chosen backing. EF can work with multiple different databases and even some NoSQL solutions, so I wouldn't necessarily rule it out here.